# Move Position of the selected segment to centre of the view HMSegmentedcontrol

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

Im using an HMSegmentedcontrol and it has 10 segments.
By Default the view display only 3 segments and the rest should be scrolled.

My Scenario:

- If I'm Selecting a Topic in my Sidemenu. It will open the VC which has  10 segments and my preselected Topic/segment is loaded and Its functioning correctly.

My Problem:

- After it Displays the VC correctly with 1st three segment is visible in the screen and the selected segment 7th is out of the screen.

My Goal:

- The Selected 7th Segment should be move its position to centre of the VC.

How Can I achieve this ?

I have Tried:

`- (void)setIndexChangeBlock:(IndexChangeBlock)indexChangeBlock;`

Since I didn't have a scrollview as the parentview, I can't move the position.

Then what else can I do to Achieve this ?

Attached code:

```
_headerScroll = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, commonWidth-10, _tvMovieView.frame.size.height-10)];
[_tvMovieView addSubview:_headerScroll];
_headerScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:81.0/255.0f green:80.0f/255.0f blue:82.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
_headerScroll.sectionTitles = titleArray;
_headerScroll.segmentEdgeInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 0, 7);

_headerScroll.segmentWidthStyle = HMSegmentedControlSegmentWidthStyleFixed;
_headerScroll.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationDown;
_headerScroll.selectionStyle  = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleTextWidthStripe;

_headerScroll.selectionIndicatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[_headerScroll addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[_headerScroll setSelectedSegmentIndex:visibleSection animated:YES];

[_headerScroll setTitleFormatter:^NSAttributedString *(HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl, NSString *title, NSUInteger index, BOOL selected) {
    NSAttributedString *attString;

    if (selected) {

        attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName:[COMMON getResizeableFont:OpenSans_SemiBold(11)]}];

        return attString;
    } else {
        attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [COMMON Common_Light_BG_Color],NSFontAttributeName:[COMMON getResizeableFont:OpenSans_SemiBold(11)]}];

        return attString;
    }
}];
```

Comment: Can you add the code please?

Comment: @Kerberos can you check now ?